# Flyway for multiple database connections (Java/Spring)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway

My Java/Springboot 2 app reads from one database and writes to a second. The code works fine (two different data sources, entity factories, directories, etc.) but i don't know how to tell Flyway to use script A to update DB A and script B to update DB B.

Googling has turned up results for different single databases in different environments and multiple databases of the same type but i haven't found the right search terms to find the answer on how to talk to two different databases with different schemas at the same time.

Comment: did you find the right way to solve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

As documented in Spring Boot documentation

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup

> You can also add a special {vendor} placeholder to use vendor-specific
>   scripts. Assume the following:

```
 spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration/\{vendor}
```

> Rather than
>   using db/migration, the preceding configuration sets the folder to use
>   according to the type of the database (such as db/migration/mysql for
>   MySQL). The list of supported databases is available in
>   DatabaseDriver.

you can just change the default location of flyway

```
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration/vendor1, classpath:db/migration/vendor2
```

Spring Boot calls Flyway.migrate() to perform the database migration. If you would like more control, provide a @Bean that implements FlywayMigrationStrategy.

Comment: i'm sorry, i don't understand how that addresses the problem. I can make 2 directories with 2 scripts and, as the page you list states, i can create two data sources. But i don't see how to map directory A to datasource A and B to B. It's not the vendor keyword you mentioned, right? Because both my scripts are Postgres and vendor doesn't say which datasource to use.